# Front headphones jacks are not working in Ubuntu (Dual boot with Windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Hello Ubuntu community

I've recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 in a dual boot configuration. However, I encountered an issue where the front headphones jack (mic & speakers) are not recognized or working while rear jacks works as usual.
Interestingly, when I boot into Windows 10, the sound works fine for both front and rear jacks. I have tried to use extra USB card in Ubuntu and it worked immediately but front audio jacks remains totally dead

I have tried using default sound configuration, Alsamixer and Pulse Volume Control to switch input and outputs but no success

My Ubuntu version is:
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Desktop

My PC is: HP Envy 810-290nz

My sound card is integrated: Integrated IDT 92HD68E2 Audio

Let me know if you have some ideas,
Thank you